# Setting spatial reference for MapInfo tab-file

Tags: mapinfo, coordinate-system

How can I change spatial reference for tab-file in MapInfo Professional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first way is File > Save Copy As and from here click Projection button which locate in the lower right. and the second method i always use is that Tools > Universal Translator > Universal Translator...

i hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

Operation "Reproject" can be done via `File > Save Copy As` as stated @Aragon

If you need to do "Define projection" instead of "Reproject" then operation is slightly more complex:

1. Export data to MID/MIF
2. Open MIF file in Notepad
3. Find line starting with `CoordSys` and change description of coordinate system. You can find right description by making export of any data in that target coordinate system and then just copying needed line from MIF file.
4. Import data from MID/MIF in MapInfo.

I think you can find some additional MapBasic (mbx) utilities which will help to do this in more easy way.