# Saving spatial reference of MapInfo TAB-file to file (like .prj)

Tags: mapinfo, coordinate-system

I have some MapInfo TAB-file and I'd like to save spatial reference to [.prj-file](http://en.geopublishing.org/Format_PRJ_file). How it can be done?

Comment: duplicate or a continuation of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22298/setting-spatial-reference-for-mapinfo-tab-file

Comment: @DanPatterson: I admit that my English is not good. First question is about changing spatial reference and this question is about saving spatial reference to file. These are two different questions about spatial reference in mapinfo. Why do you think that there is a duplicate question? Perhaps this question can be considered as a continuation of previous question in some senses. But is this a crime?

Comment: Loom  Perhaps editing the original question would be best so that the information could be tied together to facilitate searching this site regarding MapInfo projection information.

Comment: @DanPatterson: I understand now. No, these questions are not tied together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Universal Translator**

MapInfo comes bundled with Universal Translator which can be found under the Tools menu. It is an additional option so may not be installed but should be on your installation disc. This should create a .prj file, like in Uffe's answer.

**MapBasic**

If you are doing this regularly/in bulk you could make a MapBasic program to do it for you. The following command will show you the prj string for the last table to be opened. You could then either copy and paste the result into a file or work some more Mapbasic magic to make it do it for you.

```
Include "mapbasic.def"
Print CoordSysStringToWKT$(TableInfo(0, TAB_INFO_COORDSYS_CLAUSE))
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert it to a SHP file with FWtools / ogr2ogr and you've got your PRJ file.